Puzzle solving algorithm (not a jigsaw puzzle)
I have spent the past week coding an app that should take an image, which is divided into x rows and y cols, shuffled around, and put it back into its original state without any info about the original image. I've checked over the internet and I couldn't find any good way of solving this. Most people here talk about jigsaw puzzles only, which is a lot easier to do due to having the edge shape as well to work with.
I have ran into a problem where I can't thing of a good algorithm to do this properly. At first I tried to use genetic algorithm to solve it, however, that also requires a very great algorithm and I didn't like how it was always taking differently long and always produced different results (which is most likely my fault due to the algorithm for giving fitness values being not exactly great). Anyways, I remade the app to not use genetic algorithm and just use normal code to give each piece some fitness values to fitting with another piece and trying to build an image from there.
Example of such scrambled image is here: Scrambled image 
What I am doing now for the algorithm is using edge detection on the pieces and then taking the pieces with the least amount of "edge" in it. However, this is not perfect and therefore the algoritm has a success rate of around 20% only.
Therefore, could I maybe get any other ideas of what algorithm to do or how to improve it?
Here is the main part of the code getting the fitness initially
def get_piece_fitness(self):  # checks how likely each piece is to be next to each other

        for piece_one in self.image_pieces:
            Helper.get_certain_loading(current_progress=piece_one.index + 1, final_num=len(self.image_pieces),
                                       description="Getting fitness values of piece edges: ")
            right_edge_fit_likelihood = []
            left_edge_fit_likelihood = []
            top_edge_fit_likelihood = []
            bottom_edge_fit_likelihood = []
            for piece_two in self.image_pieces:
                if piece_two != piece_one:  # check whether the pieces aren't the same piece

                    # concatenating horizontally on both sides at once to save on computing power
                    horizontal_edge_fit = np.concatenate(
                        [piece_two.gray_piece, piece_one.gray_piece, piece_two.gray_piece], axis=1)
                    horizontal_edge_likelihood = self.get_edge_fitness(horizontal_edge_fit, is_horizontal=True)

                    left_edge_fit_likelihood.append((piece_two, horizontal_edge_likelihood[0]))

                    right_edge_fit_likelihood.append((piece_two, horizontal_edge_likelihood[1]))

                    vertical_edge_fit = np.concatenate(
                        [piece_two.gray_piece, piece_one.gray_piece, piece_two.gray_piece])
                    vertical_edge_likelihood = self.get_edge_fitness(vertical_edge_fit, is_horizontal=False)

                    top_edge_fit_likelihood.append((piece_two, vertical_edge_likelihood[0]))

                    bottom_edge_fit_likelihood.append((piece_two, vertical_edge_likelihood[1]))

            piece_one.left_edge_candidates = left_edge_fit_likelihood
            piece_one.right_edge_candidates = right_edge_fit_likelihood
            piece_one.bottom_edge_candidates = bottom_edge_fit_likelihood
            piece_one.top_edge_candidates = top_edge_fit_likelihood

    def get_edge_fitness(self, image: np.ndarray, is_horizontal: bool) -> tuple[float, float]:
        image_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)  # image blur
        edges = cv.Canny(image=image_blur, threshold1=30, threshold2=self.contrast)  # Canny Edge Detection

        if is_horizontal:
            edges_width = edges.shape[1]
            left_edge = np.array(edges[:, (edges_width // 3) - 1: (edges_width // 3)])
            right_edge = np.array(edges[:, (edges_width // 3) * 2 - 1: (edges_width // 3) * 2])

            left_edge_length = left_edge.size
            right_edge_length = right_edge.size

            left_edge_likelihood = np.sum(left_edge) / left_edge_length
            right_edge_likelihood = np.sum(right_edge) / right_edge_length

            return left_edge_likelihood, right_edge_likelihood
        else:
            edges_height = edges.shape[0]
            top_edge = np.array(edges[(edges_height // 3) - 1:(edges_height // 3)])
            bottom_edge = np.array(edges[(edges_height // 3) * 2 - 1:(edges_height // 3) * 2])

            top_edge_length = top_edge.size
            bottom_edge_length = bottom_edge.size

            top_edge_likelihood = np.sum(top_edge) / top_edge_length
            bottom_edge_likelihood = np.sum(bottom_edge) / bottom_edge_length

            return top_edge_likelihood, bottom_edge_likelihood

Quick edit:
As a user, the app is receiving several arguments to help with the initial part, such as the number of columns and rows in the puzzle image. This part of the code deals with the pieces that are already correctly extracted from the puzzle image.

This sounds to me like a boundary value problem. On the matching edges of two puzzle pieces, the difference between the line of pixels has to be minimal. The challenge is to find the edges itself. A possible approach is to use Fourier transformation, if the puzzle pieces are of the same size. Then you could filter the according spatial frequencies in Fourier space and try to find the edges after back transformation.

my first idea is the same as @JMP two matching pieces should have similar pixels on the touching edges - so this could be used to find matching pieces. And after shuffling they should have many different pixels on the touching edges - so this can be used to find edges. I would check columns 1,2, next columns 2, 3, etc and check which pairs are more different. Eventually I would divide width  by 2 (and check columns in this place) to check if it has only 2 columns of pieces next I would divide width by 3 (and check columns in these place) to check if it has 3 columns of pieces,etc. Less work.

Those are great ideas. As for the automating the edge detection to find the pieces, for now, I just give it number of rows and cols as input. I will think about it later

I propose the following:
Extract the set of all edges with a width of 1 pixel. Calculate the Hausdorff distance between each pair of edges, considering pixel number as x and color as y. Note that the color can be broken down into 3 components, in which case you end up with sets of (x, r, g, b) points. A weight alpha can be given x to give more or less emphasis to pixel relative location.
Once all of the pairs are obtained, you can start assembling the puzzle by first matching the closest edges and recursively building from there. I would backtrack if no edge exists with an "acceptable" distance is found.

I will have to read up more on the Hausdorff distance to be able to fully implement this but thanks for the idea!

I have given it a try and it failed miserably to compare the edges of images. I thought comparing edge to edge should be easy but it's not the case. I tried to come up with some other distances by it also failed. Accordingly, I think that other methods involving machine learning might be better. You would need a large set of images that you would split and then label each couple of images as 1 or 0 for match or not match.
